# javascript new object constructor function alternative proper?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor, new-operator

Okay, so I've been reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new
And find myself writing a bunch of object construction code in a class sort of scheme.

To maintain backward compatibility I haven't been using 'class' keyword/syntax much.

You may have seen this before:

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
//Usage: var carinstance = new Car("blah","blah","blah");
```

But I've found that this works quite well for my use (found by accident):

```
function Player (name) {
    var p = {
        name : name,
        age : 18
    };
    return p;
}
//Usage: var person = new Player("Jon");
```

**I know it works**, as I've used it. **I just don't know if this is proper.**

For example, I can use the same code w/o 'new' keyword (same result):

```
var person = Player("Jon");
```

But I cannot do the same with the first specification (using 'this' keyword in a function):

```
var car = Car("blah","blah","blah"); //car == undefined
```

I don't really know how to google this, or what to call it. I was hard enough trying to figure out what title this question should have.

I guess a more definitive way to put the question:
Are the results I'm getting just a quark of javascript, browser engine, etc? Or is this a solid way to make a constructor function?

Comment: Your first approach uses constructor as you are using `this` and you will have to use `new` or `Object.create` to create object. In your second approach, you are returning an object but it does not uses a constructor. 1 major difference will come into play when you start using `prototype`. An object created with `new` will have your defined prototype and other one will only have default prototype

Comment: Yes, this is a quark of how `this` works in JavaScript. Not affiliated to the below channels, but these are great resources to learn about what's going on here!

[The new keyword](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3zzCY62NYc)
....
["this & Object Prototypes"](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `Player` function, it returns `p` object. So, if you use `new` operator call `Player` function, it will be `p` object but not the default created obj.Of course, it will also return `p` object when you call `Player` in general. However, in `Car` function, it doesn't return an object.Therefore, when you use `new` operator call `Car` function, it will return the default created an object and it will return `undefined` with calling `Car` function in general.

you can refer:

[usage of new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
    if ( !(this instanceof Car) )
      return new Car(make, model, year);
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
```

and then you can call it without new.